# Jenkins on Kubernetes JNLP Failed to connect to jenkins.example.de:50000

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, agent

I recently enabled RBAC at Kubernetes. Since than, Jenkins (running on Kubernetes, creating agent-pods on the very same Kubernetes) is able to create agent-pods, but is unable to connect to JNLP via Port 50'000.

I noticed a reference for `Connecting to jenkins.example.de:50000`, but did not find where this is configured, as it must resolve Kubernetes-Internal (Kube-DNS), as the port is not exposed from outside.

I noticed (and updated) configuration at `Configure System` > `Jenkins Location` > `Jenkins URL`, leading to failed RBAC logins (Keycloak), as redirect URL is set incorrectly. Futher it does not feel correct for configuring cluster-internal endpoints for JNLP. I can chose between JNLP being able to work with cluster-internal URL or Being able to login, using RBAC:

[image]

### Questions

- How to configure Jenkins URL correclty? (https:(jenkins.example.com?)
- How to configure Jenkins JNLP correclty (jenkins-svc.jenkins.cluster.local:50000)? Where to do so?

### Pod Information

```
kubectl get all -o wide -n jenkins

NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE                 NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/jenkins-64ff7ff784-nq8jh   2/2     Running   0          22h   192.168.0.35   kubernetes-slave02   <none>           <none>

NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)              AGE   SELECTOR
service/jenkins-svc   ClusterIP   10.105.132.134   <none>        8080/TCP,50000/TCP   68d   app=jenkins

NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES                   SELECTOR
deployment.apps/jenkins   1/1     1            1           68d   jenkins      jenkins/jenkins:latest   app=jenkins

NAME                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES                   SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/jenkins-64ff7ff784   1         1         1       68d   jenkins      jenkins/jenkins:latest   app=jenkins,pod-template-hash=64ff7ff784
```

```
kubectl describe -n jenkins pod/worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-2jm7b
Name:                      worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-2jm7b
Namespace:                 jenkins
Priority:                  0
Node:                      kubernetes-slave/192.168.190.116
Start Time:                Fri, 08 Jan 2021 17:16:56 +0100
Labels:                    istio.io/rev=default
                           jenkins=jenkins-slave
                           jenkins/label=worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897
                           jenkins/label-digest=9f81f8f2dabeba69de7d48422a0fc3cbdbaa8ce0
                           security.istio.io/tlsMode=istio
                           service.istio.io/canonical-name=worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-2jm7b
                           service.istio.io/canonical-revision=latest
Annotations:               buildUrl: https://jenkins.example.de/job/APP-Kiali/job/master/63/
                           cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.4.247/32
                           cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 192.168.4.247/32
                           prometheus.io/path: /stats/prometheus
                           prometheus.io/port: 15020
                           prometheus.io/scrape: true
                           runUrl: job/APP-Kiali/job/master/63/
                           sidecar.istio.io/status:
                             {"version":"e2cb9d4837cda9584fd272bfa1f348525bcaacfadb7e9b9efbd21a3bb44ad7a1","initContainers":["istio-init"],"containers":["istio-proxy"]...
Status:                    Terminating (lasts <invalid>)
Termination Grace Period:  30s
IP:                        192.168.4.247
IPs:
  IP:  192.168.4.247
Init Containers:
  istio-init:
    Container ID:  docker://182de6a71b33e7350263b0677f510f85bd8da9c7938ee5c6ff43b083efeffed6
    Image:         docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.8.1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://istio/proxyv2@sha256:0a407ecee363d8d31957162b82738ae3dd09690668a0168d660044ac8fc728f0
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      istio-iptables
      -p
      15001
      -z
      15006
      -u
      1337
      -m
      REDIRECT
      -i
      *
      -x

      -b
      *
      -d
      15090,15021,15020
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 08 Jan 2021 17:17:01 +0100
      Finished:     Fri, 08 Jan 2021 17:17:02 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  128Mi
    Environment:
      DNS_AGENT:
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-7htdh (ro)
Containers:
  kubectl:
    Container ID:  docker://fb2b1ce8374799b6cc59db17fec0bb993b62369cd7cb2b71ed9bb01c363649cd
    Image:         lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl:latest
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl@sha256:47e2096ae077b6fe7fdfc135c53feedb160d3b08001b8c855d897d0d37fa8c7e
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      cat
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 08 Jan 2021 17:17:03 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /home/jenkins/agent from workspace-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-7htdh (ro)
  jnlp:
    Container ID:   docker://58ee7b399077701f3f0a99ed97eb6f1e400976b7946d209d2bee64be32a94885
    Image:          jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://jenkins/inbound-agent@sha256:62f48a12d41e02e557ee9f7e4ffa82c77925b817ec791c8da5f431213abc2828
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Fri, 08 Jan 2021 17:17:04 +0100
      Finished:     Fri, 08 Jan 2021 17:17:15 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  256Mi
    Environment:
      JENKINS_PROTOCOLS:          JNLP4-connect
      JENKINS_SECRET:             ****
      JENKINS_AGENT_NAME:         worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-2jm7b
      JENKINS_DIRECT_CONNECTION:  jenkins.example.de:50000
      JENKINS_INSTANCE_IDENTITY:  ****
      JENKINS_NAME:               worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-2jm7b
      JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR:      /home/jenkins/agent
    Mounts:
      /home/jenkins/agent from workspace-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-7htdh (ro)
  istio-proxy:
    Container ID:  docker://9a87cafa07779cfc98c58678f484e48e28e354060573c19db9d3d9c86be7a496
    Image:         docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.8.1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://istio/proxyv2@sha256:0a407ecee363d8d31957162b82738ae3dd09690668a0168d660044ac8fc728f0
    Port:          15090/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      proxy
      sidecar
      --domain
      $(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
      --serviceCluster
      worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-2jm7b.jenkins
      --proxyLogLevel=warning
      --proxyComponentLogLevel=misc:error
      --concurrency
      2
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 08 Jan 2021 17:17:11 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   128Mi
    Readiness:  http-get http://:15021/healthz/ready delay=1s timeout=3s period=2s #success=1 #failure=30
    Environment:
      JWT_POLICY:                    first-party-jwt
      PILOT_CERT_PROVIDER:           istiod
      CA_ADDR:                       istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
      POD_NAME:                      worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-2jm7b (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:                 jenkins (v1:metadata.namespace)
      INSTANCE_IP:                    (v1:status.podIP)
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT:                (v1:spec.serviceAccountName)
      HOST_IP:                        (v1:status.hostIP)
      CANONICAL_SERVICE:              (v1:metadata.labels['service.istio.io/canonical-name'])
      CANONICAL_REVISION:             (v1:metadata.labels['service.istio.io/canonical-revision'])
      PROXY_CONFIG:                  {"proxyMetadata":{"DNS_AGENT":""}}

      ISTIO_META_POD_PORTS:          [
                                     ]
      ISTIO_META_APP_CONTAINERS:     kubectl,jnlp
      ISTIO_META_CLUSTER_ID:         Kubernetes
      ISTIO_META_INTERCEPTION_MODE:  REDIRECT
      ISTIO_METAJSON_ANNOTATIONS:    {"buildUrl":"https://jenkins.example.de/job/APP-Kiali/job/master/63/","runUrl":"job/APP-Kiali/job/master/63/"}

      ISTIO_META_WORKLOAD_NAME:      worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-2jm7b
      ISTIO_META_OWNER:              kubernetes://apis/v1/namespaces/jenkins/pods/worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-2jm7b
      ISTIO_META_MESH_ID:            cluster.local
      TRUST_DOMAIN:                  cluster.local
      DNS_AGENT:
    Mounts:
      /etc/istio/pod from istio-podinfo (rw)
      /etc/istio/proxy from istio-envoy (rw)
      /var/lib/istio/data from istio-data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/istio from istiod-ca-cert (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-7htdh (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  workspace-volume:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  default-token-7htdh:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-7htdh
    Optional:    false
  istio-envoy:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     Memory
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  istio-data:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  istio-podinfo:
    Type:  DownwardAPI (a volume populated by information about the pod)
    Items:
      metadata.labels -> labels
      metadata.annotations -> annotations
  istiod-ca-cert:
    Type:        ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:        istio-ca-root-cert
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  26s   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned jenkins/worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-2jm7b to kubernetes-slave
  Normal   Pulling    24s   kubelet            Pulling image "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.8.1"
  Normal   Pulled     21s   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.8.1" in 2.897659504s
  Normal   Created    21s   kubelet            Created container istio-init
  Normal   Started    21s   kubelet            Started container istio-init
  Normal   Pulled     19s   kubelet            Container image "lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl:latest" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    19s   kubelet            Created container kubectl
  Normal   Started    19s   kubelet            Started container kubectl
  Normal   Pulled     19s   kubelet            Container image "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    19s   kubelet            Created container jnlp
  Normal   Started    18s   kubelet            Started container jnlp
  Normal   Pulling    18s   kubelet            Pulling image "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.8.1"
  Normal   Pulled     11s   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.8.1" in 7.484694118s
  Normal   Created    11s   kubelet            Created container istio-proxy
  Normal   Started    11s   kubelet            Started container istio-proxy
  Warning  Unhealthy  9s    kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://192.168.4.247:15021/healthz/ready": dial tcp 192.168.4.247:15021: connect: connection refused
  Normal   Killing    6s    kubelet            Stopping container kubectl
  Normal   Killing    6s    kubelet            Stopping container istio-proxy
```

### Logs: Jenkins Agent

```
fabiansc@Kubernetes-Master:~$ kubectl logs -n jenkins pod/worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-2jm7b
error: a container name must be specified for pod worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-2jm7b, choose one of: [kubectl jnlp istio-proxy] or one of the init containers: [istio-init]
fabiansc@Kubernetes-Master:~$ kubectl logs -n jenkins pod/worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-2jm7b -c kubectl
fabiansc@Kubernetes-Master:~$ kubectl logs -n jenkins pod/worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-2jm7b -c jnlp
unable to retrieve container logs for docker://58ee7b399077701f3f0a99ed97eb6f1e400976b7946d209d2bee64be32a94885fabiansc@Kubernetes-Master:~$ kubectl logs -n jenkins pod/worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-2jm7b -c jnlp  -c jnlppod/worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-t57rw
error: expected 'logs [-f] [-p] (POD | TYPE/NAME) [-c CONTAINER]'.
POD or TYPE/NAME is a required argument for the logs command
See 'kubectl logs -h' for help and examples
fabiansc@Kubernetes-Master:~$ kubectl logs -n jenkins  -c jnlp pod/worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-t57rw
Error from server (BadRequest): container "jnlp" in pod "worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-t57rw" is waiting to start: PodInitializing
fabiansc@Kubernetes-Master:~$ kubectl logs -n jenkins  -c jnlp pod/worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-t57rw
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up agent: worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-t57rw
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM hudson.remoting.Engine startEngine
INFO: Using Remoting version: 4.3
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /home/jenkins/agent/remoting as a remoting work directory
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to /home/jenkins/agent/remoting
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among []
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Agent discovery successful
  Agent address: jenkins.example.de
  Agent port:    50000
  Identity:      cd:35:f9:1a:60:54:e4:91:07:86:59:49:0b:b6:73:c4
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to jenkins.example.de:50000
fabiansc@Kubernetes-Master:~$ kubectl logs -f -n jenkins  -c jnlp pod/worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-t57rw
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up agent: worker-c82ea4bd-52e1-47c6-bad7-4a416a1e6897-z1bn0-t57rw
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM hudson.remoting.Engine startEngine
INFO: Using Remoting version: 4.3
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /home/jenkins/agent/remoting as a remoting work directory
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to /home/jenkins/agent/remoting
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among []
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Agent discovery successful
  Agent address: jenkins.example.de
  Agent port:    50000
  Identity:      cd:35:f9:1a:60:54:e4:91:07:86:59:49:0b:b6:73:c4
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:07 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to jenkins.example.de:50000
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:17 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to jenkins.example.de:50000 (retrying:2)
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to jenkins.example.de:50000
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoint.java:247)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.connectTcp(Engine.java:844)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:722)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:518)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:645)
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoint.java:205)
        ... 3 more

Jan 08, 2021 4:18:17 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:18 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Protocol JNLP4-connect encountered an unexpected exception
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionRefusalException: Connection closed before acknowledgement sent
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.util.SettableFuture.get(SettableFuture.java:223)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:743)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:518)
Caused by: org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionRefusalException: Connection closed before acknowledgement sent
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.AckFilterLayer.onRecvClosed(AckFilterLayer.java:283)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecvClosed(ProtocolStack.java:816)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.NetworkLayer.onRecvClosed(NetworkLayer.java:154)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.BIONetworkLayer.access$1500(BIONetworkLayer.java:48)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.BIONetworkLayer$Reader.run(BIONetworkLayer.java:247)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:117)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Jan 08, 2021 4:18:18 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted
java.lang.Exception: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.onConnectionRejected(Engine.java:828)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:768)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:518)
```

### Logs: Jenkins Agent

```
INFO: Connecting to jenkins.example.de:50000 (retrying:2)
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to jenkins.example.de:50000
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoint.java:247)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.connectTcp(Engine.java:844)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:722)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:518)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:645)
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoint.java:205)
        ... 3 more

Jan 08, 2021 4:18:17 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect
Jan 08, 2021 4:18:18 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Protocol JNLP4-connect encountered an unexpected exception
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionRefusalException: Connection closed before acknowledgement sent
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.util.SettableFuture.get(SettableFuture.java:223)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:743)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:518)
Caused by: org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionRefusalException: Connection closed before acknowledgement sent
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.AckFilterLayer.onRecvClosed(AckFilterLayer.java:283)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecvClosed(ProtocolStack.java:816)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.NetworkLayer.onRecvClosed(NetworkLayer.java:154)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.BIONetworkLayer.access$1500(BIONetworkLayer.java:48)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.BIONetworkLayer$Reader.run(BIONetworkLayer.java:247)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:117)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Jan 08, 2021 4:18:18 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted
java.lang.Exception: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.onConnectionRejected(Engine.java:828)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:768)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:518)
```

Comment: I noticed an environment variable `JENKINS_DIRECT_CONNECTION` for `JNLP` container. I do think it must be overwritten.

Comment: I found a setting at `Configure Clouds`, when disabling both `WebSocket` and `Direct Connection`. This way I can set `https-svc.jenkins.cluster.local:50000/`, but causes `SEVERE: Failed to connect to https://jenkins-svc.jenkins.cluster.local:50000/tcpSlaveAgentListener/: jenkins-svc.jenkins.cluster.local
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to https://jenkins-svc.jenkins.cluster.local:50000/tcpSlaveAgentListener/: jenkins-svc.jenkins.cluster.local
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:217)`

Comment: Noticed configuration must be `jenkins-svc.jenkins.svc.cluster.local`, not `jenkins-svc.jenkins.cluster.local` (note `.svc.`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer. `Istio` was delaying connectivity of `JNLP`. Details on [Github Issue #146](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-inbound-agent/issues/146). Further, `Jenkins URL` **and** `Jenkins Tunnel` must be configured (otherwise it fails, see [Github Issue #788](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/788)):

[image]

Two solutions:

- Disable `Istio`
- Create your own custom `JNPLP` image, utilizing delay / retry (graceful degradation). None is provided since February 2020.

Comment: I've been stuck on exactly this problem for hours. Can't tell you how helpful this was.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, after doing lots of research later I found that problem was in service.yaml that was used to expose the jenkins server. So I changed this

```
ports:
    - name: httpport
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 32000
```

to this

```
- name: httpport
  port: 8080
  targetPort: 8080
  nodePort: 32000
- name: jnlpport
  port: 50000
  targetPort: 50000
```

And it solved my problem.

If interested, here I explained how I deployed my jenkins server on kubernetes
 [How to Deploy Jenkin on Kubernetes](https://gursewaksingh-51905.medium.com/%EF%B8%8Fdevops-how-to-deploy-jenkin-on-kubernetes-with-nfs-server-and-blue-ocean-f69f9d6dbc79)

Heres my Jenkins tunnel and Jenkins URL values looks like

[image]

Comment: You were missing exposing the pod-connection, which you did with setting a dedicated port at pod-level. Don't forget exposing it via the service. Your issue-case is very different than solution stated here some time ago.